# How to integrate BurstSMS API into asp.NET application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have situation that if anyone send `SMS` to my `virtual number(CallerID)` the `BurstSMS` API will call my handler which get the response from query string and proceed further.

So, I want to know only that ,how and which things needed to integrate the `BurstSMS` API in my `APS.NET` application.

I couldn't find the information from the documentation of  API site and as well as not any article on the google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do.

- Log in to your account
- Go to Messaging -> Keywords
- Click Edit from the Actions column of the campaign you would like to receive responses for
- In the form which pops up fill in the "Send Response to URL" field with a URL to a script on your server which can process the responses, e.g. www.clienturl.com/sms.php
- Click Save

From then on we will forward all SMSes for that campaign to your script with an HTTP GET request. For example, if you send "Property 25" to your longcode, we will call

```
www.clienturl.com/sms.php?mobile=61430008230&response=Property+25
```

From that you can see the parameters we use.

You could also add other parameters your own reference such as the longcode or an internal client id by using a different URL in the "Send Response to URL" field, e.g.

```
www.clienturl.com/sms.php?longcode=61418499440&client=123
```

In which case we would send to you

```
www.clienturl.com/sms.php?longcode=61418499440&client=123&mobile=61430008230&response=Property+25
```

Source [burstsms](http://support.burstsms.com/hc/en-us/articles/202402018-Is-there-an-API-for-URL-forwarding-)

Comment: @BaljeetSingh mark it as answer if it worked for you :)